# Change raw count to a proportion based on a filter in Tableau

Tags: tableau

In Tableau, I commonly want to carry out a task like distinguishing 2 groups by various measures.

The example below shows the difference in the count of 2 treatment and control for variable levels of a factor (measure):

[image: Tableau]

This view is misleading though, because the overall group sizes of treatment and control are not equal.

What I'd like to do is to represent this as a proportion for each levels of the factor (measure) instead of using just a count. For instance, perhaps 25% of the treatment group is in Business Development whereas only 10% of the control group is in Business Development.

Is this possible to do in Tableau, or does it strictly require pre-processing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this without reworking your, and as always, there are few ways to do it. Without seeing exact data, I would try setting table calculation to percent of total and then alter compute with to Table Down / Table Across depending on the data layout